# Carrusel Javascript error con más de un carrusel

Tags: javascript, html, carrusel

Soy nuevo en JS y vi en internet de cómo hacer un carrusel solo con html, css y js.

El problema que tengo con este carrusel es que cuando hago dos o más en la misma página, dejan de funcionar igual, el primer error que me aparece es que en vez de funcionar cada uno por separado funcionan en conjunto, ya que cuando presenta todos los slides del primer carrusel en vez de seguir en bucle ,desaparecen los del primero y siguen en el segundo y así con todos.

El segundo error que vi fue que cuando presionaba las flechas de cualquier carrusel, el primero funcionaba.

Adjunto los códigos para que me puedan ayudar por favor:

```
let indice = 1;
muestraSlides(indice);

function avanzaSlide(n){
    muestraSlides( indice+=n );
}

function posicionSlide(n){
    muestraSlides(indice=n);
}

function muestraSlides(n){
    let i;
    let slides = document.getElementsByClassName('miSlider');
    let barras = document.getElementsByClassName('barra');

    if(n > slides.length){
        indice = 1;
    }
    if(n < 1){
        indice = slides.length;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < slides.length; i++){
        slides[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    for(i = 0; i < barras.length; i++){
        barras[i].className = barras[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    slides[indice-1].style.display = 'block';
    barras[indice-1].className += ' active';

}

'''

<div class="s-contenedor">
      <p>título</p>
      <div class="slide-contenedor">
        <div class="miSlider fade">
            <img src="Imagenes/1.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="miSlider fade">
            <img src="Imagenes/2.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="miSlider fade">
            <img src="Imagenes/3.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="miSlider fade">
            <img src="Imagenes/4.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="miSlider fade">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="Imagenes/5.png" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="direcciones">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="atras" onclick="avanzaSlide(-1)">&#10094;</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="adelante" onclick="avanzaSlide(1)">&#10095;</a>
        </div>
        <div class="barras">
            <span class="barra active" onclick="posicionSlide(1)"></span>
            <span class="barra" onclick="posicionSlide(2)"></span>
            <span class="barra" onclick="posicionSlide(3)"></span>
            <span class="barra" onclick="posicionSlide(4)"></span>
            <span class="barra" onclick="posicionSlide(5)"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Sé que estoy pidiendo mucho pero si alguien pudiera decirme cómo hacer para que al presionar la última imagen me lleve a otra página traté insertando la img en una etiqueta `<a>` pero no funcionaba, ¿Tienen alguna idea?.

Gracias

Comment: Cunado dices que haces dos o más en la misma página a que te refieres? a dos carrusel o a dos Imagenes?

Comment: Ok entiendo, tienes más de dos carrusel en una página. Pero no utilizas las mismas funciones JS para los dos verdad?

Comment: ehhh, sí lo estoy haciendo, debería de usar diferentes funciones?

Answer (score 1):

**Tus primeros 2 errores** probablemente se deban a que ESTÁS USANDO LAS MISMAS FUNCIONES PARA AMBOS, prueba cambiándolas y verifica de nuevo.

Respecto a cómo hacer que al tocar la imagen abra otra página, solo agregué `target="_blank"` al atributo href y me funcionó perfectamente. Te invito a que lo revises y me digas que tal? Prueba directamente en tu código, aquí en la preview No te saldrá.

```js
let indice = 1;
muestraSlides(indice);

function avanzaSlide(n){
    muestraSlides( indice+=n );
}

function posicionSlide(n){
    muestraSlides(indice=n);
}

function muestraSlides(n){
    let i;
    let slides = document.getElementsByClassName('miSlider');
    let barras = document.getElementsByClassName('barra');

    if(n > slides.length){
        indice = 1;
    }
    if(n < 1){
        indice = slides.length;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < slides.length; i++){
        slides[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    for(i = 0; i < barras.length; i++){
        barras[i].className = barras[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    slides[indice-1].style.display = 'block';
    barras[indice-1].className += ' active';

}
```

```html
<div class="s-contenedor">
      <p>título</p>
      <div class="slide-contenedor">
        <div class="miSlider fade">
            <img src="https://initiate.alphacoders.com/images/714/cropped-500-500-714242.jpg" alt="imagen1">
        </div>
        <div class="miSlider fade">
            <img src="https://initiate.alphacoders.com/images/884/cropped-500-500-884756.jpg" alt="imagen2">
        </div>
        <div class="miSlider fade">
            <img src="https://initiate.alphacoders.com/images/553/cropped-500-500-553729.jpg" alt="imagen3">
        </div>
        <div class="miSlider fade">
            <img src="https://initiate.alphacoders.com/images/279/cropped-500-500-279686.jpg" alt="imagen4">
        </div>
        <div class="miSlider fade">
            <a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://initiate.alphacoders.com/images/797/cropped-500-500-797283.jpg" alt="imagen5 CON ENLACE"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="direcciones">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="atras" onclick="avanzaSlide(-1)">&#10094;</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="adelante" onclick="avanzaSlide(1)">&#10095;</a>
        </div>
        <div class="barras">
            <span class="barra active" onclick="posicionSlide(1)"></span>
            <span class="barra" onclick="posicionSlide(2)"></span>
            <span class="barra" onclick="posicionSlide(3)"></span>
            <span class="barra" onclick="posicionSlide(4)"></span>
            <span class="barra" onclick="posicionSlide(5)"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```